# Create API through azure using speech recognition (c++ code)

Tags: c++, azure

I have created locally a program that uses the speech recognition framework (from microphone speech to text) with my creditential but that is linked to my IP address and only one use at a time.

What I would like to do is to create an API through azure that uses my c++ code and the speech recognition framework that I have used. This api would be called through a website with a lot of user calls, with their microphone.

So my questions are:
Is it possible to create the API with the c++ code behind it?

How are the creditentials in my case handled?

Do you have any documentation on creating API with c++ code on azure?

Thanks for your feedback
Romain

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options.

### A single VM

You can just rent a VM from Azure and deploy your C++ API there. Probably put a reverse proxy in front of it (such as Nginx) for TLS termination and serving some static files. Everything is in one place but you have to do everything yourself.

Needed skills: basic server administration (Linux or Windows, your choice)
Downsides:

1. always-on and you pay for it.
2. Azure will not help you manage the OS or your service.
3. Monitoring is up to you
4. Scaling is up to you

Authentication: You can either assign an Azure AD identity to the VM and link that to your Speech service, or use an intermediate Azure Key Vault to host the API key securely.

### Azure Container Apps

You can package your C++ server into a container image and let Azure deploy and serve it for you on a predefined domain name.

Downsides: Lack of control, mostly.

Authentication: you can install Secrets to either access the Speech API directly, or credentials to a Key Vault that hosts more.